# Show that a category $\mathbf A$ is thin (resp. empty) if and only if every functor with domain $\mathbf A$ is faithful (resp. full)

Tags: category-theory

I've started to learn Category theory with "Abstract and concrete categories" book and now I'm trying to do $\mathbf 3G$ $(b)$ exercise. The book is here http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf Page $45$ in the book. I have some problems with proving the statement this way $\leftarrow$. And also have a thought that every functor from an empty category both faithful and full. So I thing that I've missed something.

Comment: No, you did not miss anything. Since an empty category is thin, your statement is consistent with the one you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer. (I feel that the other part is something wrong; perhaps need to change domain to codomain.)

Assume that every functor with domain $\mathbf A$ is faithful. Set $\mathbf B = \mathbf 1$, the terminal category. Then there is a unique functor $F \in \mathbf{B^A}$. Let $x, y \in \mathbf A$ and we may assume that $\mathbf A(x, y) \neq \emptyset$. For every set $S$ and maps $f, g \colon S \to \mathbf A(x, y)$, we have 
$$F({-}) \circ f = F({-}) \circ g \colon S \to \mathbf B(Fx, Fy)$$
 since $\mathbf B(Fx, Fy) = \{ \mathrm{id} \}$ (cf. singleton is a terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}$). Since $F$ is faithful, $f = g$. Hence $\mathbf A(x, y)$ is a terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}$ and thus a singleton. Therefore $\mathbf A$ is a thin category.

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to. All morphisms are sent to the same morphism, so if the functor is faithful, they are equal so the category is thin.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, this is a bit complicated than it should be to prove this statement only. But I wrote this way because the other part is dual and it might be easier to see the duality.

Comment: For the other part one can just consider the trivial functor into the group with two objects. This can only be full if the category is empty.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Are you talking about the functor into the group with two objects considered as category? So with one object and 2 morphisms?

Comment: @A.Gonus Yes, that one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I understood your thought, thank you very much!